# cvCaptureFromCAM() / cvQueryFrame(): get native resolution of connected camera?

Tags: opencv, resolution, video-capture, image-capture

I'm using the two OpenCV functions mentioned above to retrieve frames from my webcam. No additional properties are set, just running with default parameters.

Here cvQueryFrame() always returns frames in size 640x480, independent from the native resolution of the camera. But how can I get full size frames when I don't know the exact resolution of it and therefore can't set width and height property? Is there a way to reset these 640x480 settings? Or is there a possibility to query the device for the maximum resolution it supports?

Thanks!